# "use of deleted function" when using QTextSteam in Qt5

Tags: c++, oop, qt5

I have something like this in the header file:

```
protected:
    QFile m_batPtr;
    QTextStream stream;
```

And this in the `.cpp` file of the class(actual definition):

```
    m_batPtr.setFileName(m_path);
    if(m_batPtr.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
          stream = QTextStream(&m_batPtr);
    }
```

I get the following error :

```
batperc.cpp:18: error: use of deleted function ‘QTextStream& QTextStream::operator=(const QTextStream&)’
         stream = QTextStream(&m_batPtr);
                                       ^
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A question that can easily been answered by reading the documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `QTextStream` does not support assignment. Stream like classes often don't.

Comment: Is there any alternative for doing that?

Comment: I'm not certain, but maybe `stream.setDevice(&m_batPtr);`

Comment: @ParsaMousavi **You should read the documentation**: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html. I have never used Qt and in less than 15 seconds, I was able to find the answer **with an example** using Google.